# Atribuir ponteiro à array dentro de uma função

Tags: c, array, ponteiro

Estou tentando escrever uma função que atribua um inteiro ou uma lista de inteiros à um ponteiro, dependendo de um parâmetro. Mas a atribuição não funciona dentro dela, apenas fora:

```
void retorna_algo(int size, int* destino){
  if (size == 1){
    *destino = 1;
  } else if (size == 3) {
    destino = (int[]){1, 2, 3};
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int *ponteiro;

  ponteiro = malloc(sizeof(int));
  retorna_algo(1, ponteiro);
  printf("%d\n", *ponteiro); // Escreve "1" - como esperado

  ponteiro = realloc(ponteiro, sizeof(int)*3);
  retorna_algo(3, ponteiro);

  printf("%d | %d | %d\n", ponteiro[0], ponteiro[1], ponteiro[2]);
  // Escreve "1 | 0 | 0", basicamente mantendo o valor zerado do malloc e realloc

  return 0;
}
```

Usar `destino = (int[]){1, 2, 3};` fora da função realmente atribui a array ao ponteiro, mas dentro dela nada... Como se o escopo estivesse afetando a atribuição. Eu acho que faz algum sentido, já que é uma atribuição do ponteiro da array ao endereço do literal declarado. E o endereço do literal é descartado quando a função é terminada.

Me leva a crer que o problema está na forma como a atribuição é feita (com cast para `(int[])`), mas não consegui achar nenhum outro cast que desse certo.

Comment: O problema é o que o @Bacco já disse. O array criado dentro da função é criado em stack que é descartado mal a função termina, logo qualquer acesso a ele depois é inválido e representa *undefined behavior*

Comment: @Isac pensei em por um segundo exemplo trocando ponteiro com um static com {1,2,3} fora, mas ai acho que dependeria muito de saber como vai ser usado. Os efeitos colaterais dariam uma bela dor de cabeça, se por exemplo, tentar alterar algum valor. Faltou um pouco de contexto para sabermos o que pode ou não pode aí :) Dependendo do cenário compensa um `for` fazendo `ponteiro[0]=1; ponteiro[1]=2; ponteiro[2]=3` simplesmente, ou deixar as 3 linhas mesmo :)

Comment: @Bacco Nem eu sei direito qual o propósito disso. Só acordei com vontade de ter dor de cabeça com gerência de memória :D

Comment: @Bacco Eu acho a sua solução particularmente elegante dado o contexto que temos. Isto porque realocar um novo array com `malloc` não só parece estranho, como criaria uma fuga de memória se não tivesse um `free` do array que já tinha sido criado no `main`.

Comment: Não prometo, mas se bater alguma "inspiração" qq hora dessas elaboro melhor a resposta com algumas considerações sobre outras partes do código, e quem sabe algumas alternativas. (mas tem grande chance de eu esquecer de fazer isso :P )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que ao fazer nova atribuição dentro da função, você não está aproveitando o ponteiro original, e sim criando um novo (que é descartado no retorno).

Nestes casos, creio que fazer um cópia seja uma solução razoável:

```
void retorna_algo(int size, int* destino){
  if (size == 1){
    *destino = 1;
  } else if (size == 3) {
    memcpy(destino, (int[]){1, 2, 3}, 3*sizeof(int));
  }
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/o8EuJv)**.